# Pyspark: Handle missing values as empty string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to treat the missing values in csv as empty string. How to do it while reading the file as csv?

I've tried using spark.read.csv()..option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false") but it is treating empty values as nulls.

Answer (score 0):

use `na` with `fill` to replace all null value to empty String.

```
spark.read.csv().na.fill("")
```